# 20-day-old kitten's left eye closed for 3 days after it was open?

Tags: cats, health, infections, eye-disease

20 days ago, my female cat gave birth to 4 kittens (she's an outdoor cat).

The kittens open their eyes in the day 14 normally, 
but one of them now has an issue that wasn't there before.

One of his eyes got closed; he doesn't open it at all 
and it has some brown, dried pus around it.

[image]

The picture is a bit not clear, I took it with my phone camera, 
but you can notice there is something on his nose as well.

I didn't go to the vet because they are very expensive in my area - I can't afford it.

Also, sadly, there is no rescue or shelter in my city, 
so at least I'm trying to understand if that is an infection or something simple so I can help it myself.

Comment: You need to take the kittens (all of them) to a vet. If you can't afford that, please surrender the kittens and their mother to a rescue that can handle the expenses.

Comment: @AllisonC, sadly there is no rescue or shelter in my city and im jobless currently i cant afford to take them to the vet , if there is anything you know i can do to help them myself i'll appreciate it a lot

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! The problem with the question is: we need to guess what caused the things you described. This is not the way, questions work on stackexchange. In any case you need to have a close look to all of your kittens. If it is an infection, it is very possible, that all kittens are infected. And this one is the first, with the less powerfull immune system, which got viewable ill. If you may have a guess, which causes this, then you can ask "how to help a cat with xyz?"

Comment: I'd consider that if you go to the vet now, it is very likely that you'll get away with relatively cheap medication to resolve the problem quickly, while waiting and trying to remedy on your own might lead to a lot more expense down the road, with complications such as permanent blindness or even the need to surgically remove a severely infected eye. Especially if money is tight, you can't afford to wait. Ask a friend or relative for a small personal loan, early birthday present or whatnot. If all else fails, talk to your vet, he might be on board with you paying in installments.

Answer (score 6):

The best thing you could do is get all them checked by a vet. Given your situation, you should have a look at [I can't afford vet treatment, what are my options?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/18810/12501)

As a first aid measure, I can recommend mixing "artificial tears" to rinse the eye. Please [read here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/28285/12501) for detailed instructions.

- I would advise mixing smaller batches, but you need a precision scale to weight such a small amount of salt (0.9 grams of salt for 100 grams solution).
- If available, use pure sea salt or "fleur de sel" for the solution. The next best thing is plain (not iodized) cooking salt.
- Fill it up with sterilized water. If you don't have sterilized water, you need to dechlorinate your tap water by boiling it for 20 minutes on the stove and then letting it cool.
- You can store the solution in a jar in the fridge for up to 3 days. At the fourth day, pour away the old solution and mix a fresh batch.

To treat the eye, pour the solution over a cotton pad or folded tissue paper and gently wipe the soaked tissue over the eye. Do not put the cotton / tissue into the jar with the solution to soak it, because that way you introduce a lot of impurities like dust, bacteria and mold spores into the solution.

**Important**: If you treat several cats or both eyes of the same cat this way, you must use a fresh cotton pad or tissue paper for each eye, else you risk spreading the infection even more.

I have used the solution in the past for my dog and he accepted the treatment without shying away.